# ANC to MNL via YVR flight requirements

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, vancouver, alaska

I have a 17-yr old filipina niece who is currently in US under an immigrant visa and wishes to travel alone from Anchorage, Alaska, USA (ANC) to Manila, Philippines (MNL) via Vancouver, Canada (YVR).

Questions:

1. What are the documentation requirements for exit from ANC?
2. The travel agency is saying that Canada has entry/visa requirements even for passengers who are connecting through a final destination. What kind of visa is this, and who should process, the passenger or the agency? Can she get this upon arrival to YVR?
3. What other expenses she might encounter while in transit?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Find out if you need a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=Philippines), citizens of the Philippines usually need a visa to visit Canada, but are eligible for the Transit Without Visa (TWOV) program.

The [Determine your eligibility – Transit without a visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp) details the requirements for people who may be able to transit through Canada without a visa. From what you have described so far, your niece is likely eligible for this program.

There are no specific documentation requirements for leaving the USA, other than that which the airline requires to allow you to board a plane. Check with her airline to ensure that she has the required documentation (at least a passport and a confirmed itinerary will likely be required).

If she is not eligible for the TWOV program, she will need to [apply for a transit visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-how.asp).